# FontAwesome icons is sometimes displaying unknown letters

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

As the title says, the font-awesome font is sometimes displaying the characters in the attached picture instead of Facebook, Instagram, and Vimeo icons.

I've tried replicating the issue by blocking the font but it didn't work.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this when you are writing inline of the code.

```
<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Also, you can use with CSS as well.

```
.btn-allocate {
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        background-color: #094f70 !important;
        padding: 1.3em 1.3em 1.3em 1.3em;
        border-color: #094f70 !important;
        margin-top: 0.3em;
    }

        .btn-allocate:before {
            content: "\f14a";
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            position: absolute;
            top: -0.12em;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 2.2em;
            left: 0.16em;
        }

https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

Add this link as well within your `<head></head>` tag.

Comment: Try this and let me know when you got this. I want to help you.

Comment: Hi, I've already added ```aria-hidden="true"``` to the element but I'm not sure yet if this fix would work since it only happens sometimes.

do you mind explaining adding the aria-hidden would solve the issue?

Thanks!